# Splitting a string with conditions by Regex

Tags: php, regex, string, split

I have a string like this

> abcabdabeaf

Now I want to split it into a sequence of 'a', 'b' and any characters follow after the string 'ab' like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => c
    [3] => a
    [4] => b
    [5] => d
    [6] => a
    [7] => b
    [8] => eaf
)
```

My current attempt is

```
$string = "abcabdabeaf";
$split = preg_split("/((?<=a)b)/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
print_r($split);
```

But the result is

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
    [2] => ca
    [3] => b
    [4] => da
    [5] => b
    [6] => eaf
)
```

Is it possible to do so with regex?

Comment: your first array doesn't make sense then... Oh, you mean split if naxt letters after 'ab' are in alfabetical order?

Comment: @Kamilos it does, because right after c there's another ab sequence.

Comment: > and any characters follow after the string 'ab' so what with last 3 chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I find it easier to think of this problem in terms of matching instead of splitting:

1. Match a (if followed by b)
2. Match b (if it follows a)
3. Match anything else until 'ab' or end of string is encountered

In code:

```
preg_match_all('/a(?=b)|(?<=a)b|.*?(?=ab|$)/', $s, $matches);
// note that $matches[0] has an empty array element at the end
```

This would work too, albeit a bit more verbose than I'd like:

```
$final = array(); $first = true;
foreach (explode('ab', $s) as $part) {
        if ($first) {
                $first = false;
        } else {
                $final[] = 'a';
                $final[] = 'b';
        }
        $final[] = $part;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Jack. I have tried your code and it works nice!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use regular expressions? `explode()` is right down your alley.

```
<?php $k = "abcabdefabcabcgfgdgdfabde";
var_dump(explode("ab",$k));
?>
```

You will get an empty element if your string starts with ab. To rememdy it, simply `array_shift` the array!

Comment: Regexp version: `preg_match_all("#ab([^ab]+)#i",$k,$results);`. Absolutely overkill.

Comment: So he ask wrong question: 'Splitting a string with conditions by Regex'

Comment: Today's fortune cookie: Because you think a certain tool is the panacea, doesn't mean that the said tool is the panacea. In this case, for instance, the obvious is to think "string manipulation = POSIX regular expressions!" when in reality, there's a simple solution sitting right there.

Comment: @user1800246 Yes I do know that I can use explode() but it doesn't capture the delimiter so I'm asking for a solution with preg_split()

Comment: Closest I could get using preg_split: `/((?<=a)b|(?=a))/`. The drawback: empty tokens.